# Italian Schengen visa form session expired

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, vfs-global

My wife is applying for a Schengen tourist visa through VFS for our honeymoon to Italy. Whenever we use the VAF login to fill in the application form we fill in the first page and click save or next page and a page comes up that says 'session expired'. We cannot return to the form and when we try to login again we have to wait an hour as our account gets locked.

Has anyone else experienced this or knows any way of stopping this from happening?

Comment: Either it's a bug in the VFS software, or you are just too slow in filling it out. Try writing up everyhing in some text program, and then when you start filling out the form just copy-paste everything quickly there.

Comment: If you use some script or ad blocker try to deactivate them.

Comment: Im having the same problem. Any solution to this?

Comment: The issue continues to persist. I did not even spend 2 minutes on the page (typed really fast) and the site timed me out. Ridiculous. Can one of the VFS employees take the ownership and raise a ticket for the IT support. It will make a lot of lives easier!! (Just sent an email on the site support)

Answer (score 2):

Got the same issue on Greece Schengen visa application. After trying FF, Chrome and Edge here's a simple solution I found:

1. Install "Tab autorefresh" extension for your browser (does not matter which one).
2. Login into their portal.
3. Enable autorefresh for that tab with 10 seconds refresh
4. Duplicate tab.
5. Use this tab to complete application.

Answer (score 1):

For a technical issue or guidance, you would have to contact a VFS Global Helpline. If the centre through which you are applying does not have a local or direct contact, the UK centre gives the general emails:

info.schengen@vfshelpline.com
feedback_prs.uk@vfshelpline.com

The [FAQs also note](http://www.vfsglobal.com/italy/uk/london/faqs.html) that you can escalate the issue if necessary:

> What if I am not happy with the response I receive from the person on the helpline?
>
> You can ask for the Manager on duty at any time during your enquiry if you are unhappy with the response you have received from the helpline. You may also share any feedback about the VFS Global experience (appreciation or complaint) visiting our Customer Experience page on this website